# Bokeh datetime axis, control of minor ticks

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I have a web app that serves Bokeh plots (uses Bokeh v0.12.7). The x-axis is datetime, displaying a user-defined number of days (the date range defaults to 31 days). Without defining any tick parameters in Bokeh, the number of major ticks defaults to 5, as shown on the live web app here:

https://btac-web-plots.herokuapp.com/avyview?style=snowpacktracker

I want to display minor ticks for every day between the major ticks. I tried the following, which allows for any date range length, and specifies a major tick every 5th day (`start` and `end` are Pandas Datetime indices):

```
num_days = ((end - start) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
fig.xaxis.ticker = DaysTicker(
  days = np.arange(1, num_days, 5),
  num_minor_ticks = 4
  )
```

This correctly displays major ticks every 5th day, but minor ticks are not displayed. Another potential solution might be to plot major ticks every day, and then set tick labels to invisible for days except every 5th day (unsure how to implement this...).

**What is the best method to display daily minor ticks on these plots?**

Here is a section of my plotting code (including `DaysTicker`), using the first panel as an example:

```
fig = figure(
  title="New Snow, SWE, Snow Depth, and Settlement",
  name="newsnow_extra_fig",
  x_axis_type="datetime",
  y_axis_label='HN24 / SWE (in)',
  width=width, height=height2,
  tools=tools,
  toolbar_sticky=False,
  logo=None
  )
fig.y_range = Range1d(-12, 30)
fig.extra_y_ranges = {"Depth": Range1d(start=-72, end=180)}
fig.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Depth", axis_label='HS (in)' ), 'right')
fig.yaxis.axis_label_standoff = 5

num_days = ((end - start) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
fig.xaxis.ticker = DaysTicker(
  days=np.arange(1,num_days,5),
  num_minor_ticks=4
  )

newcds, newcds_sums = create_newsnow_extra_cds(df, 'mid', start, end)

dline = fig.line(source=newcds,
  x='Date', y='depth', 
  line_color="blue", line_width=2, line_alpha=0.5, 
  legend="snow depth (HS)", name="depthline",
  y_range_name='Depth',
  )

nsbars = fig.vbar(source=newcds,
  x='newsnow_x', width=WIDTH, bottom=0, top='newsnow', 
  color="blue", alpha=0.9, legend='new snow (HN24)', name='nsbars'
  )
swebars = fig.vbar(source=newcds,
  x='swex10_x', width=WIDTH, bottom=0, top='swex10',
  color="blue", alpha=0.3, legend='SWE x 10', name='swebars'
  )

settlebars = fig.vbar(source=newcds, 
  x='Date', width=WIDTH*2.0, bottom='settle', top=0, 
  color="orange", alpha=0.75,
  name="settlebars", legend="settlement"
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built in `DatetimeAxis` does not really expose a minor tick configuration corresponding to your use case. So your options would be:

- create a [custom extension](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) to return exactly the major and minor ticks you want
- Use a "day" ticker for every day and hide ticks you don't want to see, as you suggested.

The second path (your idea) is probably the simplest to get started. Here is a complete code sample that uses `FuncTickFormatter` to generate "blank" tick labels except every fifth day:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import DaysTicker, FuncTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure

x = pd.date_range("2017-12-01", "2017-12-31")
y = ([1,3,4]*11)[:31]

p = figure(plot_width=800, x_range=(x[0], x[-1]), x_axis_type="datetime")

p.line(x, y, line_dash="4 4", line_width=1, color='gray')

p.xaxis.ticker = DaysTicker(days=np.arange(1,32))
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.5

p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    var date = new Date(tick)
    var day = date.getUTCDate(date)
    if ( day%5 == 0 ) { return day }
    else { return "" }
""")

output_file("foo.html")

show(p)
```

That generates this output

[image]

If you want more than just the day number, you would tweak the first `if` branch in the JS code for the `FuncTickFormatter` to do more than just `return day`

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. I modified the JS to return `month` and `day` and a formatted string. Question: because I am passing `tick` to `new Date()`, is it necessary to use UTC (`getUTCdate()`)? I assume the `tick` parameter is controlled by the index of my Pandas dataframe?

Comment: When I tried without it, a datetime was returned for my local time zone, which did not seem desirable. But it may or may not be appropriate depending on your situation.

Comment: Also, concerning grid lines. Perhaps this should be a new question, but I am trying to line up the grid lines with the labeled ticks. Using `fig.xgrid.ticker = DaysTicker(days=np.arange(0,num_days,5))`, where `num_days = 31`, should put ticks at `[ 0  5 10 15 20 25 30]`. However, the grid seems to be ignoring 30 and placing a grid line at 31....?

Comment: Well, two things: first, there is no "0" day (i.e. there is no such thing as "December 0") so the sequence should not include zero (I'm not really sure offhand what BokehJS will do with a 0 in the days list, but nothing intended). Second, I *think* possibly there is some logic causing the last tick to be discarded if it is to close to the beginning of the next month. That's probably not ideal, or at least ought to be configurable. But will require new development to change, so the appropriate next step would be a GitHub issue with details.

Comment: In the mean time the only option I can think to offer is a Custom Extension ticker that.

Answer (score 2):

There's apparently functionality that's been merged that will improve the situation here, see [How do you add more x axis ticks and labels to datetime axis using Python's Bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915275/how-do-you-add-more-x-axis-ticks-and-labels-to-datetime-axis-using-pythons-boke) and https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1668